# How to generate a polynomial dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, regression

I am trying to generate a polynomial dataset. I wrote a code

```
def generate_dataset1():
    n = 500
    X = 2 - 3 * np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
    y = X - 2 * (X ** 2) + 0.5 * ( X ** 3) + np.random.normal(-3, 3, n)
    m = np.random.uniform(0.3, 0.5, (n, ))
    b = np.random.uniform(5, 10, (n, ))
    
    plt.scatter(X, y, s=10)
    plt.show()
```

Now, if I want to generate a dataset using the given formula (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20polynomial%20regression%20is,nth%20degree%20polynomial%20in%20x.&text=Such%20variables%20are%20also%20used%20in%20classification%20settings.)), could you tell me what I have to change?

```
y = B_0 + B_1*x, B_2*x2 + B_3*x3 + ... + e
```

Here, `x2` means `x (square)`, `x3` means `x (cube)`, so on and `e` is the unobserved random error with mean zero.

Comment: That's what you have, just with constants for B_0, B_1, and B_2.  What's your confusion?

Comment: How I will write the code to multiply `x` with `B`? Because, the degree is increasing with the increment of x. Say, I have to multiply B_0 with x but, I have to multiply B_1 with x2.

Comment: The easy way is to think about it as `((B_3*x + B_2) * x + B_1) * x + B_0`.  Do you see the pattern?  That's produces a cubic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to multiply `x` with `B`, such as dot product. But I think for loop should be good enough. Just loop through element of `B` and `x`:

```py
def generate_dataset(B, n):
    # B is beta, n is number of sample

    e = np.random.normal(-3, 3, n)
    X = 2 - 3 * np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(B)):
        y += B[i] * X**i
    y += e
    return X, y

def plot_dataset(X, y):
    #m = np.random.uniform(0.3, 0.5, (n, ))    # not sure why you need this
    #b = np.random.uniform(5, 10, (n, ))    # not sure why you need this

    plt.scatter(X, y, s=10)
    plt.show()

n = 500
B = [0, 1, -2, 0.5]    # [beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3]
X, y = generate_dataset(B, 500)
plot_dataset(X, y)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I want to use `np.dot`, then how, I have to write?

Comment: Not sure, maybe something like `X= 1, x, x**2, x**3], axis=1)`, then apply `y = X @ B`.